# How to match redis key patterns using native django cache?

Tags: django, django-caching

I have a series of caches which follow this pattern:

```
key_x_y = value
```

Like:

```
  'key_1_3' = 'foo'
  'key_2_5' = 'bar'
  'key_1_7' = 'baz'
```

Now I'm wondering how can I iterate over all keys to match pattern like `key_1_*` to get `foo` and `baz` using the native django `cache.get()`?

(I know that there are way, particularly [for redis](http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/), that allow using more extensive api like `iterate`, but I'd like to stick to vanilla django cache, if possible)

Comment: Are these keys available in `cache` object? Is `cache` object a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, cache object is a dict of strings saved in redis cache, and I'm going to find all values that match `key_1_*`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not possible using standard Django's cache wrapper. As the feature to search keys by pattern is a backend dependent operation and not supported by all the cache backends used by Django (e.g. memcached does not support it but Redis does). So you will have to use a custom cache wrapper with cache backend that supports this operation.

**Edit:**
If you are already using [django-redis](http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/) then you can do

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.keys("foo_*")
```

as explained [here](http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_scan_delete_keys_in_bulk).

This will return list of keys matching the pattern then you can use cache.get_many() to get values for these keys.

```
cache.get_many(cache.keys("key_1_*"))
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate with code, how can it be done in a custom wrapper?

Comment: Custom wrapper is an option when cache backend supports this feature but Django's cache wrapper does not. If backend does not support it then custom wrapper will do nothing.

Comment: As you yourself suggested in the question that it can be done using django-redis as Redis support this feature and django-redis is a custom wrapper that supports all the methods of Django wrapper plus some extra methods available only for Redis. You can look here http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_scan_delete_keys_in_bulk if you want to see how to get keys by pattern using django-redis.

Comment: Right Muhammad, so please use the most efficient way i.e `cache.get_many(cache.keys("key_1_*"))` and I'll accept the anser.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir can you explain time complexity.

Comment: @manojJadhav time complexity for searching key patterns is `O(N)` where `N` is the total numbers of keys stored in Redis database as mentioned here https://redis.io/commands/keys. Please also see the warning section on the referenced page where it states `should only be used in production environments with extreme care, it may ruin performance`.

Answer (score 2):

If the `cache` has following entries:

```
cache = {'key_1_3': 'foo', 'key_2_5': 'bar', 'key_1_7': 'baz'}
```

You can get all the entries which has key `key_1_*`:

```
x = {k: v for k, v in cache.items() if k.startswith('key_1')}
```

---

**Based on the documentation from [django-redis](http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_scan_delete_keys_in_bulk)**

You can list all the keys with a pattern:

```
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.keys("key_1_*")
# ["key_1_3", "key_1_7"]
```

once you have the keys you can get the values from this:

```
>>> [cache.get(k) for k in cache.keys("key_1_*")]
# ['foo', 'baz']
```

You can also use `cache.iter_keys(pattern)` for efficient implementation.

Or, as suggested by @Muhammad Tahir, you can use `cache.get_many(cache.keys("key_1_*"))` to get all the values in one go.

Comment: Nice but the dictionary is save in redis cache. Sorry I should have mentioned this.

Comment: There are some [guidelines](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/07/14/using-redis-as-django-session-store-and-cache-backend/) here on how to use Redis as cache backend. Have you set the cache to redis?

Comment: Yes, and I'm already using redis for sessions. That's why I don't want to break the cache by implementing third-party modules.

Comment: @AKS cache.get_many(cache.keys("key_1_*")) is a better option here. It will fetch all the keys in a single call instead of 'n' calls.

Comment: I agree that would be better. :) But, I just noticed that OP doesn't want to move away from vanilla django cache.

Comment: @AKS no away but move away vanilla django! thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I saw several answers above mentioning django-redis.

Based on https://pypi.org/project/django-redis/

You can actually use `delete_pattern()` method

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.delete_pattern('key_1_*')
```

**Avoid** using pattern matching like this in production environment. It will drain use your resource quickly. Because the operation is O(N)

From [REDIS KEYS docs](https://redis.io/commands/keys/)

> Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using SCAN or sets.